# Database installer failing to create DacStore object since updating to SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I've got an installer that creates or updates a database associated with a website.  We originally wrote the installer for Microsoft Server 2008 R2, and SQL Server 2008.  We've updated to Microsoft Server 2016, and SQL Server 2016 and I now get failures with the `dacpac`.

I've updated the DAC framework on the system, but the issue persists.  The specific part that fails is in a PowerShell script.

> New-Object : Cannot find type [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Dac.DacStore]: verify that the assembly containing this 
>       type is loaded.
>       At C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\2_ir_sf_temp_3\UnregisterDataTier.ps1:29 char:13
>       + $dacstore = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Dac.DacStore($s ...
>       +             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>           + CategoryInfo          : InvalidType: (:) [New-Object], PSArgumentException
>           + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand

The section of code (line 29 is the final line):

```
If (!$uid -And !$pwd)
{
   $serverconnection.ConnectionString  = "Server = $server; Database = $database ; Integrated Security = True;"
}
Else
{
   $serverconnection.ConnectionString  = "Server = $server; Database = $database ; Integrated Security = False; User ID = $uid; Password = $pwd;"
}

$dacstore = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Dac.DacStore($serverconnection)
```

I've been trying everything I can find with others getting the same error message, but it doesn't seem to apply to my situation.  I am assuming there was some minor change somewhere that I just cannot locate.

This works perfectly on 2008, but I cannot find what might have changed that causes this error.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm are you running this directly on the SQL 2016 server (or on a computer with only the 2016 tool set?).  According to this [MS Social page](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/0bc0a167-9faa-4dfc-bfa0-1b54f6e7b8dc/need-to-find-location-for-microsoftsqlservermanagementdacdll-to-use-sql-azure-features?forum=sqlkjmanageability), the DAC library was deprecated starting with SQL 2012.   You should be able to use the SMO libraries or other .NET libraries to create the connection string at least.  However you may need to refactor your script a little for some of your commands.

Comment: Looks like the DacStore class was removed, and there was no real replacement for it.  Going to take a lot of digging.  Thanks for the link!